# vendor folder disappears after dockerfile finish building

Tags: docker, docker-compose, swagger

The title says it all. My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
swagger:
    container_name: "swagger"
    build:
      context: web/
      dockerfile: swagger/Dockerfile
    dns:
      - "8.8.8.8"
      - "10.0.0.2"
    volumes:
      - ./web/swagger:/var/www/swagger:delegated
      - ./web/api/controllers:/var/www/swagger/controllers:ro
      - ./web/swagger/vendor:/var/www/swagger/vendor
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:zts-alpine3.11

RUN apk update && apk upgrade

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/swagger

COPY swagger/composer.json ./
COPY swagger/composer.lock ./
RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader

COPY swagger .
COPY api/controllers controllers

EXPOSE 80
CMD php -S 0.0.0.0:80
```

The build:

```
Building swagger
Step 1/11 : FROM php:zts-alpine3.11
 ---> d9293b396dfe
Step 2/11 : RUN apk update && apk upgrade
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f3ea600aa726
Step 3/11 : RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4fe1237c5dc2
Step 4/11 : WORKDIR /var/www/swagger
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c669a7b04c35
Step 5/11 : COPY swagger/composer.json ./
 ---> c5e6e3bbb97f
Step 6/11 : COPY swagger/composer.lock ./
 ---> 01e36ce086ae
Step 7/11 : RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader
 ---> Running in e08f6cf0fd92
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 6 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.2.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.17.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v5.0.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing symfony/finder (v5.0.8): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing doctrine/annotations (1.10.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing zircote/swagger-php (3.0.4): Downloading (100%)         
symfony/yaml suggests installing symfony/console (For validating YAML files using the lint command)
3 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
Removing intermediate container e08f6cf0fd92
 ---> db2db0c4240b
Step 8/11 : COPY swagger .
 ---> 04936a4370a0
Step 9/11 : COPY api/controllers controllers
 ---> d996bb813094
Step 10/11 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in 82abb1153d51
Removing intermediate container 82abb1153d51
 ---> d2be0a04a504
Step 11/11 : CMD php -S 0.0.0.0:80
 ---> Running in 73e3d941ec27
Removing intermediate container 73e3d941ec27
 ---> 1a4ae5218579

Successfully built 1a4ae5218579
Successfully tagged apogo3_swagger:latest
```

As you can see, it builds fine, and i even tried to ssh into every step after the `RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader` command, to see when the vendor folder disappear, but with no luck. It doesn't disappear at any point under the Dockerfile build process, which makes me question my `docker-compose.yml` file, more specifically in the `volumes` section. I am quite new to docker and i might have misunderstood something.

#### What i want

... is first and foremost, to be able to build it and keep the vendor folder after the build process finishes. Secondly, i want the generated vendor folder to either be persisted in the host machine or in the container, to prevent long builds.

I think i am close, anything is very appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to delete all of the `volumes:` directives.  That will use the `vendor` directory that `RUN composer install` creates and the other source code you `COPY` in, and not hide these behind possibly-empty host directories.  Docker image caching can help minimize the rebuild time, and taking advantage of this mostly requires copying only the `composer.json` file first (which you have); you don't need volumes for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Send an answer, and i'll accept & upvote :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just delete all of the `volumes:` from your `docker-compose.yml` file.

`volumes:` are a one-way "push" at container startup time: they always take the content from the host directory or named volume and replace the data from the image with that.  (There is a special case, the first time you use a named volume, where it gets preloaded with data from the image, but I wouldn't rely on this: Docker will never update the volume content because it might contain user data, and this doesn't work in clustered environments like Kubernetes.)

In your setup you're taking a couple of host directories and hiding the content from the image with those.  In particular, you are taking the empty `vendor` directory from the host and hiding the `vendor` directory in the image.  (It is not a named volume so the "populate the volume on first use" rule doesn't apply.)

All of the content you need is already in the image in the correct place, so you don't actually need `volumes:` here at all.  This also has the advantage of making the image completely self-contained: if you need to run it on some other system, you can `docker push` it to a registry, and from the remote system `docker run` it without needing a separate copy of the application code.  (Again, this is basically required in clustered environments like Kubernetes.)