# How to deploy dockerized laravel app with elastic beanstalk?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to Docker. Trying to deploy dockerized laravel app using elastic beanstalk. Current Docker files -

`docker-compose.yml` -

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: admin
    container_name: admin-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /usr/share/nginx/app/
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/share/nginx/app/
    networks:
      - app-network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: admin-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/share/nginx/app/
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

and `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

ARG uid=1000
ARG user=sammy
# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev
# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd 
RUN pecl install mongodb && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb && \
    pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
RUN pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php.ini
# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user
    
# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/app
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/app

RUN chown -R $user:$user .
USER $user

RUN chown -R $user:$user storage bootstrap/cache
RUN chmod -R 775 storage bootstrap/cache

RUN composer install
RUN php artisan cache:clear
RUN php artisan view:clear
RUN php artisan config:clear

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

It works fine at local machine when I run `docker compose up -d` only if I have already run `composer install` otherwise throws following error

[image]
It is ok for development purpose I have to run `composer install` once, but for production, I think it is not right way to manually do `composer install` every time new version is deployed. Doesn't the command `RUN composer install` at `Dockerfile` install the required dependencies? I can see progress bar of dependencies being installed but no `vendor` folder is generated if I ssh into container. Again it works fine if I ssh into instance and manually install dependencies.

I have deployed a nodejs app also successfully using elastic beanstalk. There the dependencies were installed properly using command `RUN npm install` at `Dockerfile`. I don't see any difference in the process. Do I have to include `vendor` folder also in the zip file?. Please suggest correct way to deploy.

Comment: Do you mean what does `composer install` ?

Comment: @JRichardsz What I know about `composer install` is,  it installs dependencies specified at `composer.json` at location `/vendor`.  What I'm asking is, why `/vendor` folder is not created, when I run `docker composer up -d` as I have `RUN composer install` at Dockerfile.

Comment: Your Dockerfile container the compose install statement, but you said: _It works fine at local machine when I run docker compose up -d only if I have already run composer install_. Do you mean that after `docker-compose up` you need to enter to the container and manually run `composer install` because the sentence in Dockerfile is not working?

Comment: @JRichardsz yes you are right. Dockerfile statement `composer install` shows running progress in terminal when I execute `docker compose up -d` but doesnt create any /vendor folder. I have to manualy execute `composer install`

Comment: We need to debug it! In your Dockerfile, after composer install, print the content of /usr/share/nginx/app/vendor folder `ls -la /usr/share/nginx/app` and also attach the relevant part of your docker build log. I saw something similar with apache2: In build process some folder existed but after docker run, folder dissapeared

Comment: @JRichardsz Got the issue. The volume that I'm mounting at `docker-compose.yml` points the same folder at `WORKDIR` defined at  `Dockerfile`. The mounted volume is one way. After removing the volume at `docker-compose.yml`, the Dockerfile script is working as expected otherwise the mounted volume makes sure that everything remains same as it is on host. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61984330/vendor-folder-disappears-after-dockerfile-finish-building]